# Add a button in foreach loop in php

Tags: php, yii

Each school has multiple payment records. I have a `summary` page where im displaying only 3 records and i have created another detail page where im displaying all payment records for that particular school. Im using Yii Framework.

For example, I have a school, which has total of `10 payment records`. I'm using `foreach` loop to display only 3 records on summary page. But what i want now is to `add a button` on summary page. As you know total records are `10` then after those 3 records on summary page, I want to display a button which will be linked to detail page where im showing all records.

and secondly, I don't want to display a button if records are already 3, if records are more than 3 then it should display a `View More` button. Where should i put button in my code?

How can i achieve this? Here is my `foreach` loop showing 3 records.

```
<?php
   $i = 0;
   foreach($model->payments as $modelPayment){ ?>
   <tr>
       <td><?PHP echo $modelPayment->amount; ?></td>
       <td><?PHP echo $modelPayment->deposit_date; ?></td>
   </tr>
   <?PHP
       $i++;
       if($i==2){
          break;
          }
    } 
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using Yii, so add `count($model->payments) > 3` this to your if statement like this below.

```
<?PHP
$i++;
if($i==3){
      if(count($model->payments) > 3){
        ?>
        <tr>
        <td><button class="btn btn-warning btn-md">More</button></td>
        </tr>
<?php
}
break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
   $i = 0;
   foreach($model->payments as $modelPayment){ ?>
   <tr>
       <td><?PHP echo $modelPayment->amount; ?></td>
       <td><?PHP echo $modelPayment->deposit_date; ?></td>
   </tr>
   <?PHP
       $i++;

       if($i==2){

          if(count($model->payments) > 3){
             <!-- Check the total size of $model and if the value is more than 3 then add the view more button-->
             <tr><td><!--Add button view more--></td></tr>
          }
          break;
       }
    } 
?>
```